# Stopwatch implementing python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this code for an assignment:

```
from stop_watch import StopWatch
size = 1000000
stopWatch = StopWatch()
sum = 0
for i in range(1, size + 1):
    sum += i

stopWatch.stop()
print("The loop time is", stopWatch.get_elapsed_time(), "milliseconds")
```

I have to create a class which generates a stopwatch and this is my code:

```
import time

class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self.start

    def stop(self):
        self.stop = time.time()
        return self.stop

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        print(str(self.stop-self.start))
```

I get this error:

```
File "week33.py", line 10, in <module>
print("The loop time is", stopWatch.get_elapsed_time(), "milliseconds") 
  File "/Users/Marinkton/Desktop/stop_watch.py", line 16, in get_elapsed_time
print(str(self.stop-self.start))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'method'
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I could not discover a mistake.

Comment: You can't name your functions and your properties the same thing.

Comment: What Morgan Thrapp said.  Change the name of your function, or your variables.

Comment: You also never call `start`, due to the renaming of you methods (e.x `self.stop = time.time()`) stop will be a float, but `start`, which hasn't been called, will still point to a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't name your functions and your properties the same thing. When you do `self.stop = time.time()`, you overwrite the function `stop`.

You need to change the name of the internal fields.

```
import time

class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = 0
        self.stop_time = 0

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        return self.start_time

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_time = time.time()
        return self.stop_time

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        print(str(self.stop_time - self.start_time))
```

PS: You're never calling start in your code.

Comment: Also, `return` in `get_elapsed_time` or `None` is returned which probably isn't his intent.

Comment: and obviously, this would make a lovely context manager but that's another story.

Comment: Yes this is now printed:
1475604305.064963
The loop time is None milliseconds

It should print the elapsed time right?
How do i fix that?

Comment: @mrobertini1239 instead of `print(str(self.stop_time - self.start_time))` in `get_elapsed_time` use `return str(self.stop_time - self.start_time)`

Comment: You're completely correct on returning instead of printing. I was leaving that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Yes, why does print doesn't work and return does?

Comment: Because they're different things? `print` prints data, and `return` returns data from a function. `print` returns `None`, so when you return `print` from a function, it returns `None`.